# Parsing the data from an Arduino

Tags: python, parsing, split, arduino

I have data from an Arduino which is from a sensor which reads like this:

```
Machine is ON
.id : 0x10
EMR 3 SENT on 46
Emergency from 20 --> Helmet @4.24m
id : 0x10
EMR 3 SENT on 46
Emergency from 20 --> Helmet @4.30m
id : 0x10
EMR 3 SENT on 46
Emergency from 20 --> Helmet @4.30m
$id : 0x10
EMR 3 SENT on 46
Emergency from 20 --> Helmet @4.39m
Machine is ON
```

I want to collect the ids, after the 0x, and also collect the no after EMR 3 Sent on 46 - the number 46, and the distance which is after @.

How should I go about it?

I am confused; beginner in Python.

Comment: It's not easy to understand your input data, try to edit your post please and maybe write exactly what is your desired output. Have you tried something? Maybe with `.split()`?

Comment: You have not mentioned if you are trying to read these values in Python or C/Arduino. I am guessing an Arduino with sensors is sending this data via Serial port to your Pi or other computing device that you want to use Python on. Do you control the C code on the arduino? If so change the values sent to be in one line and comma separated. (Don't send any non essential text). Then split each line into mutliple values in Python. If not, you'll need to write a loop that reads three lines at a time in Python and then split each line to get values.

Comment: edit your question and make everything is clear with your own codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, we have as input:

```
input = """
        .id : 0x10
        EMR 3 SENT on 46
        Emergency from 20 --> Helmet @4.24m
        """
```

Desired output is:

1. the number after "0x", in this example "10"
2. the number after "SENT on", in this example "46"
3. the number between "@" and "m", in this example "4.24"

So we'll use `split` and hope the input structure doesn't change as you gave in your example:

```
id = input.split("0x")[1].split("\n")[0]
emr = input.split("SENT on ")[1].split("\n")[0]
distance = input.split("@")[1].split("m")[0]
```

If that doesn't work and there are no new lines at your input, we'll split a bit differently to detect the end of line.

```
id = input.split("0x")[1].split("EMR")[0]
emr = input.split("SENT on ")[1].split("Emergency")[0]
distance = input.split("@")[1].split("m")[0]
```